# Unable to generate plantuml diagram when trying to use "iplantuml" in Jupyter Notebook within vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, plantuml

I'm trying to use iplantuml in jupyter notebook within VS Code.

[image]

Keep getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('plantuml', '', '@startuml\nAlice -> Bob: Authentication Request\nBob --> Alice: Authentication Response\n@enduml\n')

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2541, in InteractiveShell.run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2539 with self.builtin_trap:
   2540     args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2541     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2543 # The code below prevents the output from being displayed
   2544 # when using magics with decorator @output_can_be_silenced
   2545 # when the last Python token in the expression is a ';'.
   2546 if getattr(fn, magic.MAGIC_OUTPUT_CAN_BE_SILENCED, False):

File c:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\iplantuml\__init__.py:101, in plantuml(line, cell)
     99 output = None
    100 if use_web:
--> 101     output = plantuml_web(uml_path)
    102 else:
    103     plantuml_path = os.path.abspath(args.plantuml_path or PLANTUMLPATH)

File c:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\iplantuml\__init__.py:68, in plantuml_web(*file_names, **kwargs)
     57 """
     58 Given a list of UML documents, generate corresponding SVG diagrams, using
     59 PlantUML's web service via the plantweb module.
...
   1553     self._close_pipe_fds(p2cread, p2cwrite,
   1554                          c2pread, c2pwrite,
   1555                          errread, errwrite)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

If I hover over the `import iplantuml` I see this error:

> "iplantuml" is not accessed Pylance

I can generate a plot using matplotlib. It is only plantuml I'm unable to use

I tried doing an extra step below but then I ran into another issue of module not found and pip install didn't resolve it either. Also, didn't have to do this when I was using jupyter notebook within anaconda

```
   %load_ext plantuml_magics
```

I
What am I missing?